# How to call User-defined function in SELECT statement with Column Name as parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2005

I want to call UDF that returns `table` in SELECT statement as below.

```
select *, GetIptoCountry(IP_address) as country from tblInfo
```

but I am getting following error

> 'GetIptoCountry' is not a recognized built-in function name.

`IP_address` is the column in `tblInfo`.

How can I call UDF like this?

Comment: Try calling `GetIptoCountry` function along with the schema name. For example, **`dbo.GetIptoCountry`**.

Comment: @Wanderer I tried but getting this error `Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.GetIptoCountry", or the name is ambiguous.` but select dbo.GetIptoCountry('') works.

Comment: In a perfect world you would rewrite your scalar function as a table valued function and enjoy the performance benefit and flexibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the fully qualified name of the function including the schema name :

For example (if the scema is `dbo`), you can call the function with `dbo.GetIptoCountry()`:

```
select *, dbo.GetIptoCountry(IP_address) as country from tblInfo
```

UPDATE:

According your last comment, you seems to have a **table-valued function** (wich returns table rows), not a **scalar-valued function** (wich returns a value), so the call can be done like this:

```
Select * from dbo.GetIptoCountry('your_ip_adress');
```

Your final query can looks like:

```
select * 
from tblInfo 
cross apply dbo.GetIptoCountry(IP_address)  tblCountry
```

Comment: I tried but getting this error Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.GetIptoCountry", or the name is ambiguous. but `select dbo.GetIptoCountry('')` works

Comment: @Imad probably you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Imad Are you sure your function is a scalar-function ? not a table-valued ?

Comment: Function was returning tablular value and cross apply worked for that.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was much more simple.  I had reconnected to the database.  SSMS still had me as using the Master Database.

I just click the drop down or run a "USE MyDatabase" statement and voila.